# How to generate an optimal order of multiple elements based on pairwise element score values

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I have a number of elements, let say `[a, b, c, d]`, and for each pairwise combination I have a score:

```
[['d-a', 0], ['a-b', 0], ['b-a', 0],
 ['a-c', 2], ['c-a', 0], ['a-d', 2],
 ['d-b', 1], ['b-c', 2], ['c-b', 0],
 ['b-d', 2], ['d-c', 2], ['c-d', 2]]
```

I am looking for a way in Python to put these elements in successive order in a way that will minimize the sum of these scores. Each unit must occur once and only once. Notice that the succession of two elements is also of importance, i.e. `'d-a' = 0` while `'a-d' = 2`.

I'll be very grateful for your answers.

Thank you

Simon

Comment: Sorry, but the task is not clear to me. Please some sample output and show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: If I understand well, you want to find a permutation of `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` which minimize the sum of the scores. And the sum of the scores of `['c', 'b', 'd', 'a']`, for example, is `score('c', 'b') + score('c', 'd') + score('c', 'a') + score('b', 'd') + score('b', 'a') + score('d', 'a')`. Is that right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elements = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
scores = [['d-a', 0], ['a-b', 0], ['b-a', 0], ['a-c', 2], ['c-a', 0], ['a-d', 2],
          ['d-b', 1], ['b-c', 2], ['c-b', 0], ['b-d', 2], ['d-c', 2], ['c-d', 2]]

s = dict(scores)
print(min(itertools.permutations(elements),
          key=lambda p: sum(s[a+'-'+b] for a, b in zip(p, p[1:]))))
```

Prints `('c', 'a', 'b', 'd')`.